# Find a Facebook user account id or profile pic and user name from mobile number

Tags: facebook, fbsdk

I want to get a user profile image and facebook name from an account by his mobile number. just like the [eyecon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eyecon.global&hl=en&gl=US) app when we search a mobile number for example 0317xxxxxxx it is returning my Facebook name and profile picture. I have searched the graph API but this needs a user must be logged in.

Comment: There is no official API for that. Any service that offers this, must presumably be acquiring their data by scraping.

Comment: I have checked that. and for some time it worked fine. getting photos from multiple social media ccounts but after some time we got blocked.